# error con el tamaño de una matriz en c++

Tags: c++, array, matrices, dev-c++, c++17

estoy aprendiendo a programar en c++ y me he encontrado con una duda que no he podido responder. Tengo entendido que si necesito hacer un arreglo de, por ejemplo, 5 posiciones, puedo definir un arreglo con [4], tomar el 0 como la primera posición de mi arreglo y el 1 como la quinta. ejemplo:

```
int variable[4];

variable[0]=1;
variable[1]=2;
variable[2]=3;
variable[3]=4;
variable[4]=5;
```

Sin embargo, al pedirle al usuario que ingrese los datos para 12 posiciones, subordinadas en 3 posiciones, el for se detiene en la segunda repetición. Se entiende mejor con el ejemplo:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
     double cp[2][11],prombebidas,total[2],mayor=0,
mesmayor,mayorconservas=0,mesmayorconservas,menor=1000,rubromenor;
int i,a;
string rubro;

total[0]=0;
total[1]=0;
total[2]=0;

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    if (i==0)
    {
        rubro="conservas";
    }
    else if (i==1)
    {
        rubro="dulces";
    }
    else if (i==2)
    {
        rubro="bebidas";
    }
    for (a=0;a<12;a++)
    {
        cout<<"Ingrese los costos de producción que obtuvo el departamento de "<<rubro
        <<" para el mes "<<a+1<<": $";
        cin>>cp[i][a];
        cout<<endl;
        if (cp[i][a]>=mayor)
        {
            mayor=cp[i][a];
            mesmayor=a+1;
        }
        total[i]+=cp[i][a];
        if (cp[0][a]>mayorconservas)
        {
            mayorconservas=cp[0][a];
            mesmayorconservas=a+1;
        }

    }
    if (total[i]<menor)
    {
        menor=total[i];
        rubromenor=i;
    }
}
}
```

El programa se ejecuta correctamente los datos para conservas y para dulces, pero después de eso se detiene. El problema se resuelve si defino la matriz "cp" con los valores de cp[3][11]. Sin embargo, me gustaría saber por que no es posible hacerlo del modo que planteé originalmente. Gracias de antemano si has leído hasta aquí, estaré atento a cualquier respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Estás declarando la matriz de la siguiente manera:

`double cp[2][11]`

Eso significa que los índices irán en el primer caso de 0 a 1, y en el segundo de 0 a 10.

Al dimensionar la matriz, indicas cuantos elementos quieres guardar en cada dimensión, pero las posiciones siempre iniciarán en 0 y finalizarán en el número inmediato anterior.

Si pruebas esto, debería fallarte en la última línea:

```
int variable[4];

variable[0]=1;
variable[1]=2;
variable[2]=3;
variable[3]=4;
variable[4]=5; <== aquí
```

Answer (score 0):

Cuando declaras una matriz, lo que pones en los corchetes es el tamaño que tendrá, si necesitas 5 posiciones debes indicarlo de la siguiente manera ***int variable[5];*** y al momento de recorrerlo debes hacerlo desde su **indice 0** que en este caso sera de 0 a 4, por ejemplo:

```
int tamanio = 5;
int variable[tamanio];

for (int i = 0; i < tamanio; i++) {
    variable[i] = i;
}
```

En ese caso, se define un array de 5 posiciones, pero se comienza recorriendo desde el indice 0 (valor inicial de i) y al ser un menor restrictivo se detiene en el indice 4 del array. Si llegáramos al indice 5, sobrepasaríamos el tamaño de nuestro array y podria darnos error o escribir en una zona de memoria no controlada.

```
variable[0]=1;
variable[1]=2;
variable[2]=3;
variable[3]=4;
variable[4]=5; <-- Hasta aquí OK
variable[5]=6; <-- Escritura fuera de la memoria definida.
```

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a Pablo CG y DarkFrostnight por contestar a este post. Parece que había interpretado los arreglos de forma incorrecta. De cualquier modo, si alguien comete el mismo error:

```
int variable[2];
```

el número entre corchetes, que en este caso sería dos, es el número de posiciones que declaras en la memoria para la matriz. Las posiciones de la matriz arrancan siempre desde 0 y continuan hasta el número inmediatamente anterior al definido entre corchetes. Para nuestro ejemplo, en el que definimos 2 posiciones, la matriz iría desde 0 a 1:

```
variable[0]=1;
variable[1]=2;
```